# How to break a PHP multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, implode

Say I have this PHP array()

**$tour_from array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dhaka
            [1] => noakhali
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chittagong
            [1] => Sylhet
        )

)
```

I want to make like this:

> Dhaka - Noakhali
>   Chittagong  - Sylhet

How can I do this?

**I used this but it's the wrong way:**

```
foreach ($tour_from as $key => $value) {
    $chunk = array_chunk($value, 2);
    foreach ($chunk as $key1 => $value1) {
       echo $value1[$key][$key1] . ' - ' . $chunk[$key][$key1];
       echo '<br/>';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating it a bit. Why not just loop over the outer array and implode the inner array?

```
<?php

$tour_from = [
    ['Dhaka', 'Noakhali'],
    ['Chittagong', 'Sylhet'],
];

foreach ($tour_from as $elem) {
    print implode(' - ', $elem);
    print '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for chunking or a second loop.

One loop containing [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will do.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e58144a54221e6948fd79dcff370c5006a188ff3))

```
$tour_from = [
    ['Dhaka', 'Noakhali'],
    ['Chittagong', 'Sylhet']
];

foreach ($tour_from as $row) {
    echo implode(' - ', $row), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Dhaka - Noakhali
Chittagong - Sylhet
```

---

Alternatively, if you like a functional one-liner: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12cdb075f5535428be1aec32d5443185ffa4d233))

```
echo implode("<br>", array_map(function($row){ return implode(' - ', $row); }, $tour_from));
```

*The advantage to this is there is no trailing `<br>` on the final imploded string.

---

Or with fewer function calls, here is a version with `array_reduce()`: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b64837f58d33966201ef55d523f98e754544c7cc))

```
echo array_reduce($tour_from, function($carry, $row) {
    return $carry .= ($carry !== null ? "<br>\n" : '') . $row[0] . ' - ' . $row[1];
});
```

Comment: Bro you're in my head.

Comment: Yes, but I'd say it shouldn't. Well done seeing that and testing it out both ways. PHP functions... they always have little surprises.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `foreach` you can do the same thing with `array_walk` and pass by reference `&$var`.

```
$array = [
    ["Dhaka", "noakhali"],
    ["Chittagong", "Sylhet"]
];

array_walk($array, function(&$item){
    $item = implode(' - ', $item);
});

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Dhaka - noakhali
    [1] => Chittagong - Sylhet
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e7ad0ab08671721597a3c759662c1b7067f6071)

If you want to output it instead of modify the array you can just echo it instead or do something like `implode('<br>', $array)` afterwords.

Answer (score -1):

OH, Yes, I found the way:

```
foreach ($tour_from as $key => $value) {
    $chunk = array_chunk($value, 2);
    foreach ($chunk as $key1 => $value1) {
       echo implode(' - ', $value1);
       echo '<br/>';                                                  
    }
 }
```